# Holoviews plot not rendered in cell in JupyterLab

Tags: bokeh, jupyter-lab, holoviews

I recently tried running the `1-Introduction.ipynb` notebook in holoviews-examples in jupyterlab 0.32.1 with bokeh 0.12.16, holoviews 1.10.7 and jupyterlab_pyviz 0.5.2 installed. The plots don't seem to be rendered in a cell, however; moreover, I can't move the plot around or delete it (see the below example for when I run the first cell in the notebook containing a scatter plot):

[image: Holoviews plot not rendered in cell]

Any thoughts as to what could be causing this? I don't have this problem if I use bokeh directly.

Comment: This is likely related to https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/2850. For now we support JupyterLab 0.32.0. I'd also suggest upgrading to bokeh 0.13.0.

Comment: Actually 0.32.1 is supported so I suspect another jupyter lab extension which registers a mime type renderer for javascript is interfering (as described in https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/2876).

Comment: I had the beakerx-jupyterlab extension installed - disabling it fixed the problem.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm going to try to figure out how we can ensure that our mime extension takes absolute precedence and get back to you.

Comment: This issue is not limited to beakerx interaction. I have the latest version of everything, with no extensions in jupyter lab, but I'm still getting bad renders like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404505/holoviews-chart-not-going-away-even-after-jupyter-lab-notebook-is-closed

Answer (score 3):

Per [philippjfr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1459141/philippjfr), the presence of the beakerx-jupyterlab extension was interfering with holoviews; disabling the former fixed the problem.

Comment: I have just published jupyterlab_pyviz 0.5.3. If you've got a minute would you mind trying it in combination with beakerx?

Comment: When I tried running `jupyter labextension install --dev @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz`, yarn appeared to stall during the "Resolving packages" stage.

Comment: I believe this is an incompatibility between latest node and yarn. The issue and workarounds are documented here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4585

Comment: (Reverted to nodejs 9.11.1) The updated extension appears to properly render plots even when the beakerx-jupyterlab extension is enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

with JupyterLab 1.x I had as well the issue that all processes of bokeh/holoviews run to create an interactive plot [with box_selection] but to see it rendered so that it could be used interactively, I had to update the following:

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_bokeh
jupyter labextension install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on WSL Linux (Ubuntu) and had the same issue, with newest dependencies installed (conda-forge):
[image]

What did the trick for me was uninstall yarn, reinstall yarn and then let jupyter lab rebuild the extension. Then the overlapping bokeh/holoviews graphics disappeared.

1. Remove yarn:

```sh
sudo apt-get remove yarn && sudo apt-get purge yarn
```

2. Install yarn:

```sh
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

3. Start jupyter lab & click yes when requested to building pyviz extension.