# Holoviews chart not going away, even after jupyter lab notebook is closed

Tags: jupyter, bokeh, jupyter-lab, holoviews

My problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351467/holoviews-plot-not-rendered-in-cell-in-jupyterlab/51351587) question.

I'm not able to remove a chart I originally rendered with holoviews, despite shutting everything down. I'm reduced to opening the ipyb in sublime to see if I can find the relevant json section and rip it out *by hand*.

In fact, please reference that link to see the example screenshot, since I can't share anything which contains company data.

However, unlike that question, I don't have any extensions installed:

`jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v0.34.9
No installed extensions`

Here are the relevant versions:

`conda list|egrep -e "holoviews|bokeh|jupyter"
bokeh                     1.0.1                 py36_1000    conda-forge
holoviews                 1.10.9                     py_1    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0

jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py36_1

jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py36_0

jupyterlab                0.34.9                   py36_0

jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                   py36_0`

I rendered a (sankey) chart with holoviews and it was rendered outside the cell, at the top of the jupyter lab screen. Now, the chart won't go away, despite the following:

1. Restart the kernel
2. Clear all cells
3. Shut down the kernel, close the lab, make sure it is not running! Yes, the chart survives even closing the originating jupyter lab window!